# specifying width and height of actors

Tags: libgdx, scene2d

I am using horizontal and vertical group to create a layout as seen in a photo.  The problem is that I don't know how to specify how wide each group should be. In my case, the vertical group gets squeezed together and this results in really small UI component. The docs talk about preferred size to be the indicator of how width and tall Actors are, but there is no method like setPreferredWidth() method.  So how do I specify the width and height of Actor entities. I tried using `setWidth(), setBounds()` but these doesn't work.

[image]

backbone of my setup now. I currently have only 1 actor in vertical group.

```
mySlider=new Slider(1,100,1,false,ss);
        mySlider.setBounds(0,0,300,30);
        mySlider.setWidth(300);
        verticalGroup=new VerticalGroup();
        verticalGroup.setWidth(300);
        verticalGroup.addActor(mySlider);


        horizontalGroup=new HorizontalGroup();
        horizontalGroup.setBounds(stage.getWidth() - 120, stage.getHeight() - 125, 400, 100);
        horizontalGroup.setPosition(stage.getWidth() - 120 - 350, stage.getHeight() - 125);
        horizontalGroup.setWidth(400);
        horizontalGroup.addActor(buttonLeftToTheVerticalGroup);
        horizontalGroup.addActor(verticalGroup);
        stage.addActor(horizontalGroup);
```

Comment: Are these groups inside a Table? When something is inside a table, you set its size by setting the size of the table cell that contains it and also calling fillX or fillY on the cell if you want the actor inside it to stretch to fit the cell. If they are not inside a table you can call setWidth directly on the VerticalGroup.

Comment: it is not in table. However, setWidth still doesn't work. I also tried setScale, no success. Vertical group is around 80px wide. far from expected 300.